# Como ordeno un array de fechas, compuesto por año/mes/dia hora:minutos:segundos:milisegundos

Tags: jquery, array

Tal vez podrían ayudarme orientarme sobre como puedo ordenar un array de menor a mayor compuesto de fechas que esta concatenado de la siguiente manera:

año/mes/dia hora:minutos:segundos:milisegundos

```
 0: "2017/4/21 16:0:6:40"
​

    1: "2017/4/24 7:40:44:983"

​

    2: "2017/5/22 14:14:5:733"

​

    3: "2017/5/22 16:46:51:53"

​

    4: "2017/5/23 9:44:12:913"
    ​
    5: "2017/5/23 9:49:13:946"
    ​
    6: "2017/5/23 9:56:12:83"
    ​
    7: "2017/5/24 14:55:27:970"
    ​
    8: "2017/5/24 14:55:36:140"
    ​
    9: "2017/5/24 14:55:41:6"
    ​
    10: "2017/5/24 14:55:50:446"
    ​
    11: "2017/6/6 14:12:20:820"
    ​
    12: "2017/6/6 14:17:47:796"
    ​
    13: "2017/6/6 14:21:9:536"
    ​
    14: "2017/6/20 15:21:7:140"
    ​
    15: "2017/6/22 15:50:57:590"
    ​
    16: "2017/8/4 16:37:23:760"
    ​
    17: "2017/9/14 9:12:7:986"
    ​
    18: "2017/9/14 9:23:5:596"
    ​
    19: "2017/9/14 9:41:21:890"
    ​
    20: "2017/6/20 10:53:32:820"
    ​
    21: "2017/6/20 15:49:12:686"
    ​
    22: "2017/7/31 15:53:58:430"
```

muchas gracias !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te sugiero realices esto que te ayudara a ordenar un array de menor a mayor las fechas :

```
//funcion para ordenar el array
array.sort(function(a,b){
  var c = new Date(a.date);
  var d = new Date(b.date);
  return c-d;
});
```

Este sería un ejemplo completo:

```js
var array = [
  {id: 1, date:'2017/5/24 14:55:41:6'},
  {id: 2, date:'2017/7/31 15:53:58:430'},
  {id: 3, date:'2017/4/21 16:0:6:40'},
  {id: 4, date:'2017/4/24 7:40:44:983'},
  {id: 5, date:'2017/5/23 9:49:13:946'}
];
//funcion para ordenar el array
array.sort(function(a,b){
  var c = new Date(a.date);
  var d = new Date(b.date);
  return c-d;
});
//imprimir el array ordenado
console.log(array.sort());
```

Que tendría como salida el array de fechas ordenado de menor a mayor:

```
[
  {
    "id": 3,
    "date": "2017/4/21 16:0:6:40"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "date": "2017/4/24 7:40:44:983"
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "date": "2017/5/23 9:49:13:946"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "date": "2017/5/24 14:55:41:6"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "date": "2017/7/31 15:53:58:430"
  }
]
```

Espero te sirva. Saludos.

Comment: no me resulto funcional tu aporte :( !

Comment: Te surge error o porque no?

Comment: no me surge error ni nada, no me hace nada !

Comment: Te dejo el ejemplo en  [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MBgxPG?editors=1010).